# How to tell what DLL's a Mono/Gtk# app depends on (Windows)

Tags: c#, windows, mono, gtk#

I have a simple gtk# mono app running on windows. It works fine on my PC which has Mono, .NET, and GTK installed. But if I give the exe to a friend it obviously doesn't work.

Mono's mkbundle tool doesn't seem to work on windows without an enormous amount of hassle (I've tried). So I've reverted to the quick solution of just including the necessary DLL's with the exe when giving it to a friend.

But I don't know what is required. My guesses so far have been wrong. I tried including everything that mkbundle wanted to embed, but that didn't work. Is there some tool that can tell me what I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new console project (example name InspectRefAssm), paste this inside of it:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace InspectRefAssm
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length < 1 || string.IsNullOrEmpty(args[0]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This program requires an argument to the path of the executable.");
                Console.WriteLine("Example:");
                Console.WriteLine(Path.GetFileName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location) + @" c:\Path\To\Executable.exe");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                return;
            }

            if (!File.Exists(args[0]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("File not found.");
                Console.ReadKey(true);
                return;
            }

            Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(args[0]);

            foreach (AssemblyName asmName in asm.GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(asmName.FullName);
            }

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Compile it, then call it with:

InspectRefAssm.exe "Path\To\YourExecutable.exe"

This uses reflection to determine the libraries referenced by the executable file. If you have multiple files that are part of your executable, you may need to run this for every file, or you can modify it to be recursive, I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

Comment: This app works great, I included the DLL's in the app and gave it to my friend. And yet the app still does not work. He has .NET on his computer. Does he need mono as well?

Comment: I don't think that's correct. http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/gtksharp/beginners-guide/ It says here it's a common misconseption that Gtk# requires Mono. Sadly it still doesn't solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to distribute a program made with Gtk#/Mono, then you need your friend to install [Gtk# for Windows](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win). Once this is installed, just copy and execute the exe, and you're done.

Comment: Yea, I got it sorted, thank you for your help, although this isn't technically the question I asked. I gave you an upvote instead.

Comment: That's probably because your question was more complex than it needed to be... I mean, if you use Gtk#, install Gtk#. ;-)

It is not just a matter of DLL's, since you need the C#'s DLL's, and then the native, Gtk ones. So it is not a simple matter.

Comment: Fair point. I realised this when the referenced assemblies didn't work by themselves. I appreciate your help.